# Unable to shuffle an Array , possible fix?

Tags: python

Trying to implement an Encryption Algorithm, Here's the source code so far:

```
import random
import itertools
msg = input(" Enter the KEY :  ")
ascivalue = sum(ord(ch) for ch in msg)
a = []
i=0
b = [None] * 16
c = [None] * 26
d = [None] * 26
print("ASCII VALUE=", ascivalue)
print('')
# print('The Shuffeled values    are : \n')
for x in range(ascivalue):
    a.append(x)
    random.Random(4).shuffle(a)
    #a.append(random.randint(1, ascivalue))
# print('\t\t',a)
for x in range(16):
    b[x] = a[x]
print( "\n16 randomly generated numbers are : \n ")
print('\t\t',b)
for i in range(16):
    d = b[i] % 26
    # m = d
    if (c[d] == None):
        c[d] = d
    else:
        while (c[d] != None):
            d = d + 1
            if d == 26:
                d = 0
    c[d] = d
print("\n After normalization numbers are :\n")
random.Random(4).shuffle(c)
# print('\t\t',c)
print('')
while None in c:
    c.remove(None)
print('\t\t',c)

e = [None] * 16
f = [None] * 16
g = [None] * 16
i = 0
for i in range(16):
    e[i] = c[i] + 64
    if(e[i] == 64):
        f[i] = chr(90)          # corresponding character of each values
    else:
        f[i] = chr(e[i])
    i = i + 1

print("\nRandomly generated English letters – playfair cipher grid is : ")
print('')
for row in range(4):
    for col in range(4):
        print(f.pop(), end=' ')
    print()
# print('\nascii value of characters in the keygrid is: ')
# for i in range(16):
#     g[i] = ord(f[i])
#     i = i + 1
# print('')
# print('\t\t',g)

print('')
lst = list(itertools.product([1, 0], repeat=4))
print('The 4*4 Binary grid is : ')
print('')
for row in range(4):
    for col in range(4):
        print(lst.pop(), end=' ')
    print()

bn = ['0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111']
minpos = []
bngrid = [None] * 16
for x in range(16):
    minpos = c.index(min(c))
    if c[minpos] == 100:
        break
    bngrid[minpos] = bn[x]
    c[minpos] = 100
print('\n shuffeled bngrid using the keygrid is :\n\t\t')
print(bngrid)
print()

 for row in range(4):
     for col in range(4):
         print(bngrid.pop(), end=' ')
         print()


bn1 = ['AA', 'AT', 'AG', 'AC', 'TA', 'TT', 'TG', 'TC', 'GA', 'GT', 'GG', 'GC', 'CA', 'CT', 'CG', 'CC']
minpos1 = []
bngrid1 = [None] * 16
for x in range(16):
    minpos1 = c.index(min(c))
    if c[minpos1] == 100:
        break
    bngrid1[minpos1] = bn1[x]
    c[minpos1] = 100
print('\n shuffeled bngrid using the keygrid is :\n\t\t')
print(bngrid1)
print()

# for row in range(4):
#     for col in range(4):
#         print(dnagrid.pop(), end=' ')
#     print()
```

And the issue is, I am able to shuffle the values in :

```
bn = ['0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111']
```

However, not in :

```
bn1 = ['AA', 'AT', 'AG', 'AC', 'TA', 'TT', 'TG', 'TC', 'GA', 'GT', 'GG', 'GC', 'CA', 'CT', 'CG', 'CC']
```

The fact to note is, the same code is used for both purpose:

Here's the first block:

```
 bn = ['0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111']
minpos = []
bngrid = [None] * 16
for x in range(16):
    minpos = c.index(min(c))
    if c[minpos] == 100:
        break
    bngrid[minpos] = bn[x]
    c[minpos] = 100
print('\n shuffeled bngrid using the keygrid is :\n\t\t')
print(bngrid)
print()
```

Here's the second block:

```
bn1 = ['AA', 'AT', 'AG', 'AC', 'TA', 'TT', 'TG', 'TC', 'GA', 'GT', 'GG', 'GC', 'CA', 'CT', 'CG', 'CC']
minpos1 = []
bngrid1 = [None] * 16
for x in range(16):
    minpos1 = c.index(min(c))
    if c[minpos1] == 100:
        break
    bngrid1[minpos1] = bn1[x]
    c[minpos1] = 100
print('\n shuffeled bngrid using the keygrid is :\n\t\t')
print(bngrid1)
print()
```

The second block generates the output:

> [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

However, if I pass the values inside the array `bn1[]` to `bn[]` in the first block, it generates the desired output. However, does not produce the output in second block. What is possibly causing this?

Been struck here for quite some time, any help as to resolve this would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fault is at first block, you rewrote the values ofthe variable c without making, or using, a temporary array. When the second block used it, all values of c is already set to 100, thus, it immediately breaks, leaving the value of bngrid1 as an array of None.

Edit:

Say, yo can first use a fix, passing c's value to a new var:

```
bn = ['0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111']
c_temp = [ item for item in c] #don't use c_temp=c, that's wrong
minpos = []
bngrid = [None] * 16
for x in range(16):
    minpos = c_temp.index(min(c_temp))
    if c_temp[minpos] == 100:
        break
    bngrid[minpos] = bn[x]
    c_temp[minpos] = 100
print('\n shuffeled bngrid using the keygrid is :\n\t\t')
print(bngrid)
print()
```

with the second one doing the same.

Or you can make a function for it:

```
def func(c):
    bn = ['0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010', '1011', '1100', '1101', '1110', '1111']
    minpos = []
    bngrid = [None] * 16
    for x in range(16):
        minpos = c.index(min(c))
        if c[minpos] == 100:
            break
        bngrid[minpos] = bn[x]
        c[minpos] = 100
    print('\n shuffeled bngrid using the keygrid is :\n\t\t')
    print(bngrid)
    print()
```

I didn't test the code so I can't recommend copy pasting it.

Comment: You can make a function for that, that will accept you variable *c* and use it locally without affecting the original array. Or maybe, you can use another line to pass a copy of c to another var.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is quite hard to read and debug because of many variables and arrays called a, b, c etc. Next time try to post only essentials of your problem and name the variables so that it's easy to understand for someone else than you :)

About your problem - if the code works in the first part but doesn't in the second, maybe the problem is in array c (hard to say what numbers are there without going deeply in your code because again name does not say anything) but I can see that in the first part, in loop you're setting some values of c to 100. In the second you go through c again (modified c with many 100 values) and if you find 100, you break the loop. Maybe it just finds 100 at the beginning and breaks the loop in first iteration? Try to print something in each loop, so that you know at least if it goes into the loop and how many times, it will help you debugging it. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are using all the values within your c array in the block which randomises the bn array, and then setting the values to 100.

So, by the time the bn1 block runs, all calls to c.index(min(c)) return a zero.

You could try to create a copy of c before entering the bn block, and using this copy to randomise the bn1 block.